# Perl output into CSV file

Tags: perl, csv, automation

**Question:**
I would like to *print* the output into CSV file instead of in the command prompt itself.

Here is the piece of code in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $url = '<some URL>';
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( url => $url );
my %tags;
while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input') ) {
    my $id    = $tag->get_attr('id');    # get id attribute value    
    my $value = $tag->get_attr('value'); # get value attribute value
    $tags{$id} = $value;
}

for (keys %tags) {
    print "$_ => $tags{$_} \n";  
}
```

**Output in command prompt**

```
ConnectionTime => 03:20:59:46
signalstrength => Good
ulCurrentDataRate => 2.48 Kbps
batterystatus => Fully Charged
```

**Required Output in CSV file**

`ConnectionTime signalstrength ulCurrentDataRate batterystatus`
`03:20:59:46       Good        2.48 Kbps          Fully Charged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the input values in an array and then print them to a file.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $url = '<some URL>';
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => $url);
my %tags;
while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input')) {
           my $id=$tag->get_attr('id'); # get id attribute value    
           my $value = $tag->get_attr('value'); # get value attribute value
           $tags{$id}=$value;
 }
my @tags;
my @values;
for (keys %tags){
   push (@tags, $_);
   push (@values, $tags{$_});
}

open(my $OUTFILE, ">", "<outfile>" )
    or die "Unable to open <outfile> for writing : $!";
print $OUTFILE join("\t",@tags)."\n";
print $OUTFILE join("\t",@values)."\n";
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Unknown PerlIO layer "outfile" at htmlparse.pl line 22.
Unable to open <outfile> for writing : No such file or directory at htmlparse.pl   line 22.`. Here the line 22 is **open(my $OUTFILE, "<outfile>", "rw")**

Comment: @arka.b You have to replace "<outfile>" with the real file name.

Comment: I am using now as this `open(my $OUTFILE, "test.csv", "rw")` and I am getting this error *Unknown open() mode 'test' at htmlparse.pl line 22.*

Comment: Have changed my answer to `open(my $OUTFILE, ">", "<outfile>" )`. Try again.

Comment: It is working, but the entire output in two boxes. How about using comma (,) **in the excel output** `ConnectionTime,signalstrength,ulCurrentDataRate, batterystatus` and then in the next line `03:20:59:46,Good,2.48 Kbps,Fully Charged`

Comment: If you want to use comma as a seperator change `join("\t",@` to `join(",",@`. And if you are running under windows you have to change `\n` to `\r\n\`.

Comment: Small problem here, How can I fix the output in a particular cell of the CSV ?

Comment: @arka.b Sorry can't get you.

Comment: For example `imsi` was in cell `A2`, so when I rerun the code that same `imsi` is now on `G1` ..

Comment: @arka.b I have no idea how this can be happend.